# Is there any way to do scipy.optimize.minimize (or something functionally equivalent) in parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy

I have a multivariate optimization problem that I want to run.  Each evaluation is quite slow.  So obviously the ability to thread it out to multiple machines would be quite nice.  I have no trouble writing the code to dispatch jobs to other machines.  However, scipy.optimize.minimize calls each evaluation call sequentially; it won't give me another set of parameters to evaluate until the previous one returns.

Now, I know that the "easy" solution to this would be "run your evaluation task in a parallel manner - break *it* up".  Indeed, while it is possible to do this to some extent, it only goes so far; the bandwidth rises the more you split it up until splitting it up further actually starts to slow you down.  Having another axis in which to parallelize - aka, the minimization function itself - would greatly increase scaleability.

Is there no way to do this with scipy.optimize.minimize?  Or any other utility that performs in a roughly functionally equivalent manner (trying to find as low of a minimum as possible)?  Surely it's *possible* for a minimization utility to make use of parallelism, particularly on a multivariate optimization problem where there's many axes whose gradients relative to each other at given datapoints need to be examined.

Comment: Sounds like you are getting deep enough into the minimization problem that you can write it 'from-scratch'.  Treating `minimize` as a blackbox will only get you so far.

Comment: I certainly don't look forward to having to reimplement it.  Is there any sort of other (even non-python) minimization tool / library / etc?  The overhead of making external calls is nothing compared to the evaluation runtime.

Comment: Hmm, actually I think I've come up with a trick that may let me pull it off  ;)  I believe, though I haven't tried it, that you can "restart" minimize as if it never stopped by telling it to do a limited number of evaluations then restarting it with both the params and the gradient from its last run.  Well, I could run it several times with a fake eval func that returns random results and see what it params it tries to evaluate each time.  Whatever it asks for each time I can then then spawn a real evaluation for.  Whatever I have real results for, I can then return to the minimize function.

Comment: I imagine some solvers will work better than others, of course.  I would expect that some will base their next request entirely on what the last returned, while others may try to test a number of axes independently before using the returned data.

Comment: Hmmm... except that I don't see any sort of way to get the gradient out of minimize  :Þ  At least not in a way that I can subsequently re-specify.

Comment: Hello, I just  found this thread, having the same trouble with slow function for optimization. I need to run the minimize function in parallel, but when using multiprocessing pool, its even slower than with a loop. Have you come to any useful solution?